# Kак скопировать из memo в эдит первую строку а потом ещё удалить из memo

Tags: delphi

Допустим у нас много строк в мемо, нужно скопировать первую строку из мемо в едит, а затем удалить её, что бы список в мемо как бы "поднялся" на одну строку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну а в чем вопрос ?

Получение строки в мемо есть, удаление тоже.

насколько мне память не изменяет должно быть чтото типа:

```
edit1.text := Memo1.lines[0];
Memo1.lines.delete(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Делаем это, например, по нажатию кнопки:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if Memo1.Lines.Count <> 0 then // проверяем, не пустое ли мемо
   begin
    Edit1.Text:= Memo1.Lines[0]; // копируем 1ю строку мемо в эдит
    Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);       // удаляем 1ю строку мемо
   end;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Найти в потоке(в тексте memo ) первый символ перевода строки и узнать его позицию, используя функцию Pos:

> `var pos:integer;`
>
> `pos:=Pos('#10',memo1.lines.text)`

2) Удалить все символы memo, начиная с первого, и заканчивая "pos", используя функцию delete:

> ```
> var text:TstringList;
> begin
> text:=TstringList.Create();
> text.text:=memo1.lines.text;
> delete(text,0,pos);
> ...
> ```

Это, как один из многочисленных вариантов...